# How to insert a variable in a setInterval function?

Tags: javascript

I want to change the value of something variable in the all()`

```
let something = true;
function all(){
     alert("something");
}
```

Now I want to insert something variable in all `setInterval()` function and in `all()`
How should I do this all

```
setInterval(all, 1000);
```

Comment: Do you want to pass parameter to `all` method?

Comment: Add an argument  setInterval(()=>{all(somthing)},1000);

Comment: Don't alert in a loop

Answer (score 3):

```
function all(message)
{
    alert(message);
}

setInterval(all, 1000, "hello world");
```

Comment: I never notice that version! Too bad we cannot do `setInterval(all, 1000, new Date());` to make a clock

Comment: You can just get the time from within the function.

Comment: I know. But still

Comment: `console.log` is good to check your answer's functionality easily, you can keep @mplungjan 's edit ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering me on time